# Output Acronyms Fullname in Text Italic but in Acronyms Glossary Normal

Tags: formatting, acronyms, italic

I am using

```
\begin{acronym}[PHEV]
  \acro{PHEV}{\emph{Plug-in Hybrid Electric Vehicle}}
  ... 
\end{acronym}
```

in an extra tex file for my declarations of Acronyms. I use `\emph` or `\textit` to have the full name written so within my main text (`\ac{PHEV}`).

In my main tex file I include them in the frontmatter of my document via

```
\include{myacronyms.tex}
```

as a acronyms glossary. But here the acronyms full name also gets printed in italic. I want to prevent this.

Is there a workaround? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the `acronym` package does not provide a user interface for changing the appearance of the long form.

However, introducing it only requires a small change in the internal macro `\AC@acl`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\AC@acl[1]{%
  \textit{\expandafter\AC@get\csname fn@#1\endcsname\@secondoftwo{#1}}%
}
\makeatother
```

A better way IMHO is to define a user interface analoguous to `\acsfont` for the short form.

The code below does this by introducing a new macro `\aclfont` which can be changed how you need it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\AC@acl[1]{%
  \aclfont{\expandafter\AC@get\csname fn@#1\endcsname\@secondoftwo{#1}}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\aclfont[1]{\textit{#1}}

\begin{document}

\ac{PHEV} \par
short: \ac{PHEV} \par
long: \acl{PHEV}

\begin{acronym}[PHEV]
  \acro{PHEV}{Plug-in Hybrid Electric Vehicle}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image]